# Fatal Exception: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException | android.gms.ads.AdActivity (ADMOB)

Tags: android, admob, firebase-admob

Since today at an amazing speed Admob is crashing when trying to display an Add according to Firebase.

Also Crashlytics is not getting the mapping... do not know why

This happens in every version of android 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10.

**Fatal Exception: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException** 
Unable to find explicit activity class {com.myCompany.myApp/com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
com.myCompany.myApp.GameActivity.E

```
android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult (Instrumentation.java:1933)
android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity (Instrumentation.java:1616)
android.app.ContextImpl.startActivity (ContextImpl.java:904)
android.app.ContextImpl.startActivity (ContextImpl.java:882)
android.content.ContextWrapper.startActivity (ContextWrapper.java:383)
com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.Di.a (Unknown Source:9)
com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.overlay.zzn.a (Unknown Source:77)
com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.KC.a (Unknown Source:76)
com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zu.a (Unknown Source:9)
com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.cF.showInterstitial (Unknown Source:24)
com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.Cea.c (Unknown Source:7)
com.google.android.gms.ads.InterstitialAd.c (Unknown Source:2)
com.myCompany.myApp.GameActivity.E (Unknown Source:82)
com.myCompany.myApp.X.onClick (Unknown Source:4)
android.view.View.performClick (View.java:6390)
```

**Tried to reproduce the error locally, but couldn't**
This started suddenly... and is in the only app that I'm getting that error in Firebase (all are implemented the same way)

**Gradle**

```
dependencies {
...
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:18.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.2.0'
    implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.10.1'  
...
}
```

**MANIFEST**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.myCompany.MyApp"
          android:installLocation="auto">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>  
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>  
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>

    <supports-screens
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:resizeable="true"
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true"
        />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:fullBackupContent="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        >

        <uses-library
            android:name="org.apache.http.legacy"
            android:required="false"/>
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AD_MANAGER_APP"
            android:value="true"/>
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="THENUMBERFORMYADMOB"/>
        <service
            android:name=".services.MusicService"
            android:enabled="true"/>

        <meta-data
            android:name="firebase_crashlytics_collection_enabled"
            android:value="${crashlyticsCollectionEnabled}" />

        <activity
            android:name=".SplashActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".LevelsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_game"
            android:parentActivityName=".SplashActivity">
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".GameActivity"
            android:keepScreenOn="true"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_game"
            android:parentActivityName=".LevelsActivity">
        </activity>

        ...
        OTHER ACTIVITIES
        ...


    </application>
</manifest>
```

I implemented Admob accordingly to the guide.
¿Should I add an Admob activity?

In google play crash report I'm getting reports regarding

**signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR)**
WebViewGoogle.apk

```
  #00  pc 00000000008fca14  /system/app/WebViewGoogle/WebViewGoogle.apk
```

But this has been for a long time (since 1' July... when started suddenly with a spike...) and google is "fixing it"... could this be related?

Comment: Please mansion solution if you got.

Comment: Google said:
This is an intriguing concern. It is possible that ProGuard might be stripping the activity off your final build if you were using it in the first place. You may try the following fixes and see if they would work for you:

Include com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity in your AndroidManifest.xml.
Include -keep class com.google.android.gms.ads.** { *; } in your proguard-rules file if you are using it.

If the situation persists despite the above, could you then provide the details below (via Reply privately to author) so that I can investigate the issue further?